# multiple definition of XXXXX in Visual micro

Tags: c++, c, gcc, visual-studio-2013, compiler-errors

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 with Visual micro plugin for arduino boards. 
I got errors when I create a .cpp file, like in the error list below:

> Compiling 'AeroQuad' for 'Arduino Mega 2560 or Mega ADK'
>   testMotor.cpp.o:In function `writeMotors()'
>   Motors_PWM_Timer.h:multiple definition of`writeMotors()'
>   AeroQuad.cpp.o:C:\Users\Adi\Documents\Drone\AeroQuad_v3.2\libraries\AQ_Motors\Motors_PWM_Timer.h:127:
>   first defined here ld.exe:Disabling relaxation: it will not work with
>   multiple definitions testMotor.cpp.o:In function `writeMotors()'
>   Motors_PWM_Timer.h:multiple definition of`motorCommand'
>   AeroQuad.cpp.o:(.bss.motorCommand+0x0): first defined here
>   testMotor.cpp.o:(.data.numberOfMotors+0x0): multiple definition of
>   `numberOfMotors' AeroQuad.cpp.o:(.data.numberOfMotors+0x0): first
>   defined here testMotor.cpp.o:In function`commandAllMotors(int)'
>   Motors_PWM_Timer.h:multiple definition of `commandAllMotors(int)'
>   AeroQuad.cpp.o:C:\Users\Adi\Documents\Drone\AeroQuad_v3.2\libraries\AQ_Motors\Motors_PWM_Timer.h:149:
>   first defined here testMotor.cpp.o:In function`
>   initializeMotors(NB_Motors)' Motors_PWM_Timer.h:multiple definition
>   of `initializeMotors(NB_Motors)'
>   AeroQuad.cpp.o:C:\Users\Adi\Documents\Drone\AeroQuad_v3.2\libraries\AQ_Motors\Motors_PWM_Timer.h:68:
>   first defined here testMotor.cpp.o:In function`initMotors(NB_Motors)'
>   testMotor.h:multiple definition of `initMotors(NB_Motors)'
>   AeroQuad.cpp.o:\testMotor.h:22: first defined here testMotor.cpp.o:In
>   function`pulseMotors(unsigned char)' Motors.h:multiple definition of
>   `pulseMotors(unsigned char)'
>   AeroQuad.cpp.o:C:\Users\Adi\Documents\Drone\AeroQuad_v3.2\libraries\AQ_Motors\Motors.h:51:
>   first defined here Error creating .elf

I don't understand why that?

My header file is like that:

```
// testMotor.h

#ifndef _TESTMOTOR_h
#define _TESTMOTOR_h

/*Adi*/
//#define MOTOR_PWM
#define MOTOR_PWM_Timer
//#define MOTOR_APM
//#define MOTOR_I2C

#define NB_MOTOR_4
//#define NB_MOTOR_6
//#define NB_MOTOR_8



#if defined MOTOR_PWM_Timer
#include <Motors_PWM_Timer.h>


#endif

#if defined (NB_MOTOR_4)
#define NB_MOTOR 4
#define NB_MOTOR_CONFIG FOUR_Motors
#endif

void testMotor(int motor);
void initMotors(NB_Motors motorConfig);
#endif
```

In my testMotor.cpp file I'am including the `testMotor.h` file. Like in the code below:

```
#include "testMotor.h"

void testMotor(int motor) {

    for (int motorTrust = 1000; motorTrust < 1400; motorTrust += 10) {
        motorCommand[motor] = motorTrust;
        writeMotors();
        delay(200);
    }

    motorCommand[motor] = 1000;
    writeMotors();
} 

void initMotors(NB_Motors motorConfig) {
    initializeMotors(motorConfig);
}
```

I'm also including `testMotor.h` file in my .ino project. Like in the code below:

```
#include "testMotor.h"
#include "Motors.h"
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <GlobalDefined.h>
#include "AeroQuad.h"
#include "PID.h"
#include <AQMath.h>
#include <FourtOrderFilter.h>
```

My solution project is shown in the image below:

[image]

the fact is when I exclude the `testMotor.cpp` from the project it runs without errors.

Could the reason be that visual micro didn't use C++ compiler, but C compiler? Than I shoud change the compiler to C?

Can someone help me to solve the issue?

Comment: Try to keep *declarations* in header files and *definitions* in `.cpp` files.

Comment: Well you do *define* `initMotors` in the header file, so each source file ([*translation unit*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29)) where you include the header file it will be defined.

Comment: For now you could declare `initMotors` to be `inline` to work around this, but in general, as others have said, you should put function definitions in your .c/.cpp files.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg  I have initMotors in the setup() like this: initMotors(NB_MOTOR_CONFIG);

Comment: That's how you *call* the function, but it's still defined in the header file. When, how and where you call it doesn't matter, only where it's defined.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg What should I do then?

Comment: *Declare* it in the header file, just like you do with the `testMotor` function, and *defined* it in a source file.

Comment: Hmm still the same errors. Look at my updated code. You mean like this?

Comment: @AdiT - Are you making the same mistake(s) in `Motors_PWM_Timer.h` that you are/were making in `testMotor.h`?  In other words, you have implementations of functions defined in the header instead of a .c or .cpp source module?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a library called Motors_PWM_Timer.h attempts to define functions that you are also defining in your testMotor.h

*More Info*

When Visual Micro compiles it should do what the Arduino IDE does, which means the Visual Studio project is not used. The Arduino IDE can only look at the actual source files on disk so this is how things are compiled in both Arduino and Visual Micro.

Visual Micro uses the same tool chain that the Arduino IDE uses.

The Visual Studio project is purely for ease of use and to power intellisense.

The best place for [Visual Micro](http://www.visualmicro.com) help is in the dedicated [forum](http://www.visualmicro.com/forums).

Thanks